# Why won't my conversion from str to list and then conversion to int work?

Tags: python

```py
lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
nums = "0123456789"
punc = ",.!?;"
space = " "
cs = space+lower
# Dict that converts characters to numbers
chr_to_num = {}
counter = 0
for character in cs:
    chr_to_num[character] = counter
    counter += 1

enc_msg = "pmogirmkkgrydle jtuwyly"

def split(enc_msg):
    return list(enc_msg)
     
enc_msg = "pmogirmkkgrydle jtuwyly"
print(chr_to_num[tuple(split(enc_msg))])
```

My goal for the code is to return a list of numbers that correspond with each letter in enc_msg as I'm currently getting:
KeyError: ('p', 'm', 'o', 'g', 'i', 'r', 'm', 'k', 'k', 'g', 'r', 'y', 'd', 'l', 'e', ' ', 'j', 't', 'u', 'w', 'y', 'l', 'y')

Without the tuple, I get TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Running your code, I get a `KeyError`...

Comment: This code actually raises a different error: `KeyError: ('p', 'm', 'o', 'g', 'i', 'r', 'm', 'k', 'k', 'g', 'r', 'y', 'd', 'l', 'e', ' ', 'j', 't', 'u', 'w', 'y', 'l', 'y')`. This is expected because `chr_to_num` maps characters to numbers (this is also in the variable's name), but `chr_to_num[tuple(...)]` indexes it with a tuple, which certainly isn't there

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `chr_to_num[tuple(split(enc_msg))]` to mean? Why? What should be printed?

Comment: Hint: how many times should the program try to look something up in the `chr_to_num` dictionary? Is that more than once? How do you make programs do the same thing more than once?

Comment: `chr_to_num` has a bunch of single-character keys; no tuple (even a singleton tuple) will compare as equal to any such key.

Comment: For example, the letter a should correspond with the number 1, so first it splits every char in enc_msg and makes a list. I'm not sure what the tuple does but it's mean to get rid of the TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' that would be there. Finally, it will convert every char to a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Error

You are getting an error because you're calling a `chr_to_num` key which is unvalid: `tuple(split(enc_msg))`.
Just in case, to clearify, `dico["..."]` returns the value associated to `"..."` in the `dico` dictionary.

In fact, you cannot convert all the values of a tuple/list giving the tuple/list itself. You have to convert each tuple/list element individually.

### Solution

To make it work, you should iterate the `split(enc_msg)` list:

```
converted_list = []

for letter in split(enc_msg):
    converted_list.append(chr_to_num[letter])
```

Another way to code this is:

```
converted_list = [chr_to_num[letter] for letter in split(enc_msg)]
```

Answer (score 1):

> My goal for the code is to return a list of numbers that correspond with each letter in enc_msg.

Fair enough - you'll need a loop, here a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for pythonicity and brevity, to loop over the message to run the lookup for each key.

I also took the opportunity to simplify generation of `chr_to_num` to a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
cs = " " + "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
chr_to_num = {character: counter for counter, character in enumerate(cs)}
enc_msg = "pmogirmkkgrydle jtuwyly"
print([chr_to_num.get(c) for c in enc_msg])
```

The output is

```
[16, 13, 15, 7, 9, 18, 13, 11, 11, 7, 18, 25, 4, 12, 5, 0, 10, 20, 21, 23, 25, 12, 25]
```

As an aside, you would also get the same result, though somewhat less efficiently if more briefly, with

```
cs = " " + "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
enc_msg = "pmogirmkkgrydle jtuwyly"
print([cs.index(c) for c in enc_msg])
```

Answer (score 0):

Optionally (using your code):

```
[chr_to_num[x] for x in split(enc_msg)]
```